# Correct format of a persian text in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form by method post by one input which is going to has a persian text typed by user.

```
<form method="post" action="form.bc" >
    <input type="hidden" value='متن تستی' name="description" />
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

But in `form.bc` the value of input looks like `Ø§Û�Ù� Û�Ú© Ù�ØªÙ� ØªØ³ØªÛ� Ø§Ø³Øª`. Is there any javascript code to convert it to correct format:`متن تستی`

Answer (score 0):

Add a character encoding:

```
<form method="post" action="form.bc" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack Bashford for your answer.But there is not any javascript code to do this(not using accept-charset="UTF-8")?

Comment: Well, you could split into an array of ASCII values and send that, then parse it back on the server-side in `form.bc`, but that's a little tricky, and may not be supported in all browsers.